# F# List.Map using a random number

Tags: f#

I want to create a list of 20 random numbers.  I wrote this:

```
let numberList = [ 1 .. 20 ] 
let randoms = 
    numberList 
    |> List.map (fun (x) -> System.Random().Next(0,9))
```

And I got this:

```
val numberList : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20]
val randoms : int list =
  [7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7]
```

Which makes sense.  The problem is that I want to pass in a random number each time the function is evaluated like this:

```
let numberList = [ 1 .. 20 ] 
let randoms = 
    numberList 
    |> List.map (fun (Random().Next(0,9)) -> x)
```

but I am getting a "The pattern discriminator 'Random' is not defined" exception.

Am i approaching this problem the wrong way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: And when I fully-qualify the Random parameter like so: System.Random().Next(0,9), I get a This is not a variable, constant, active recognizer or literal

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# getting a list of random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062191/f-getting-a-list-of-random-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original version, you create a new Random object at each iteration.  As this is seeded with the current time, you always create the same sequence.

You need to create the object outside map like so

```
let RNG = new System.Random()
numberlist |> List.map (fun x -> RNG.Next(0,9))
```

Although a more elegant solution would be

```
let RNG = new System.Random()
let randoms = List.init 20 (fun _ -> RNG.Next(0,9))
```

Your second version fails because you are trying to treat Random as a pattern which makes no sense in this situation.