# Use SemaphoreSlim in method without exception handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, async-await, semaphore

Currently I'm struggeling with the implementation of `SemaphoreSlim` for "locking" "parts" of a method which has to be thread-safe. My problem is, that implementing this without having an overload of exception handling is very hard. Because when an exception is thrown before the "lock" will be released, it will stay there forever.

Here is an example:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _syncLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
private IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public async Task ProcessSomeThing(string input)
{
    string someValue = await GetSomeValueFromAsyncMethod(input);
    await _syncLock.WaitAsync();
    dict.Add(input, someValue);
    _syncLock.Release();
}
```

This method would throw an exception if input has the same value more than once, because an item with the same key will be added twice to the dictionary and the "lock" will not be released.

Let's assume i have a lot of `_syncLock.Release();` and `_syncLock.Release();`, it is very hard to write the `try-catch` or `.ContainsKey` or some thing else. This would totally blow up the code... Is it possible to release the lock always when an `Exception` get's thrown or some term is leaved?

Hope it is clear what I'm asking/looing for.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest **not** using `lock` or the `SemaphoreSlim`. Instead, use the right tool for the job -- in this case it would seem appropriate to use a [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) over the use of `IDictionary<string, string>` and locking and semaphore's. There have been several articles about this pattern year's ago, [here's one of the them](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/10/using-lazy-and-concurrentdictionary-to-ensure-a-thread-safe-run-once-lazy-loaded-collection/). So following this suggested pattern would look like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task<string>>> dict = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task<string>>>();

public Task ProcessSomeThing(string input)
{
    return dict.AddOrUpdate(
        input, 
        key => new Lazy<Task<string>>(() => 
            GetSomeValueFromAsyncMethod(key), 
            LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication),
        (key, existingValue) => new Lazy<Task<string>>(() => 
            GetSomeValueFromAsyncMethod(key), // unless you want the old value
            LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)).Value;
}
```

Ultimately this achieves the goal of **thread-safety** for `asynchronously` adding to your `dictionary`. And the error handling occurs as you'd expect it to, assuming that there is a `try / catch` in your `GetSomeValueFromAsyncMethod` function. A few more resources:

- [Why does ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, valueFactory) allow the valueFactory to be invoked twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611167/why-does-concurrentdictionary-getoraddkey-valuefactory-allow-the-valuefactory)
- http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2012/01/11/Sometimes-being-Lazy-is-a-good-thing.aspx

Finally, I have created [an example .NET fiddle to help demonstrate the idea](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H5TDOg).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `lock` because there is no `await` inside the protected region. That handles all of this.

If that was not the case you would either need to use `try-finally` everywhere or write a custom disposable so that you can use the scoping nature of `using`.

Comment: I also thought about the `using` patter, because this is often an elegant way. But than i need an async disposable, which is not possible as far as i know. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Release is synchronous. You can use the normal synchronous dispose pattern.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this.