# Simple SELECT WHERE LINQ Query to a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am new to LINQ,

I want to generate a list of objects from my dbcontext where a certain field is set to true.

This is what I have so far, but I am getting an error about a select?

```
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    return (from s in db.sims.Where(x=>x.has_been_modified == true) select x).ToList();               
}
```

EDIT:

```
    //Returns a list of entries which where marked as edited in the sim managment database
    private List<String> GetUpdatedEntries()
    {
        using (var db = new dbContext())
        {
            return db.sims.Where(x => x.has_been_modified).ToList();                  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`select s`, not `x` and this will work. (because you do `from s`)

shorter way

```
return db.sims.Where(x => x.has_been_modified).ToList();
```

**For your Edit**

the method return type should be a `List<Sim>`, not a `List<String>`

Comment: What type of list should my method return for this to work? See my edit. I know that I have list<String> but what type should it be?

Comment: @Zapnologica should be a `List<Sim>` (or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
return db.sims.Where(x=>x.has_been_modified).ToList();
```

1. method Linq looks cleaner here
2. you don't need to check your bool against true
3. in your previous answer you used `s` as context and selected `x`, changing to `select s` should work also
4. Consider using lazy loading and don't add `ToList` at the end of every query

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why I should use lazy loading instead of to list?

Comment: @Zapnologica performance, read this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847721/when-should-i-use-lazyt