# Lazy loading without locks in multithread application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

What will happen if two threads read this property at the same time?

```
public static HugeType HugeType
{
    get
    {
        if (tenderCache == null)
        {
            tenderCache = Config.Get<HugeType>("HugeType", null);
        }
        return tenderCache;
    }
}
```

My object is read only and it's not critical if two instances are created. Should I add locks in any case?

Comment: Note that in memory models weaker than the .NET model, it might be possible for other threads to see a non-null `tenderCache` reference, but the object it refers to is not yet fully constructed.  For example this is definitely a data race in C++.

Comment: `Config.Get<HugeType>("HugeType", null)` may be invoke more than once and last thread wins. If that doesn't hurts you, you don't need a lock.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847721/when-should-i-use-lazyt) question. Lazy<T> is what you want here.

Comment: How is Config.Get<T> implemented ? Are you ok if it's called from multiple threads at the same time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you have no synchronization it's possible for the initialization method to be called many times, possibly even if other threads have completed the initialization entirely (due to a lack of a memory barrier).  If you don't care about executing the initialization operation multiple times and it will always return the same correct value regardless of how many times it's called and even if multiple calls to it are made concurrently, then the code will certainly work, even if it won't perform as well.

Having said that, actually properly ensuring that the initialization is only done once is *very* easy, given that it's already a solved problem.  You can simply store a `Lazy<HugeType>` in your field instead of a `HugeType` and `Lazy` will take care of the initialization synchronization for you.

Comment: +1 What happens if two threads get (tenderCache == null) as true and both try and write to tenderCache = Config.Get<HugeType>("HugeType", null); at the same time? Or the first (tenderCache == null) as true tries to read tenderCache while the second is writing to it.

Comment: @Blam If both try to write the value then one will win; assuming the initialization is always creating the same value, it means that it won't matter who wins.  Writes to variables of a reference type are atomic, so if the value is being read while another thread is trying to write to it either the read happens before the write, or the write happens before the read, and those are the only options.  Getting garbage, or "the world ending" aren't possibilities.

Comment: This is actually ripe for a thread issue and so be aware of the problems that exist if you had more lines in the initialization such as adding elements to a collection. The additional lines of code inside the null check could be missed due to the conditional no longer being true eg tenderCache == null