# Static List assignment in C# is atomic

Tags: c#

According to this [reference assignment is atomic so why is Interlocked.Exchange(ref Object, Object) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192124/reference-assignment-is-atomic-so-why-is-interlocked-exchangeref-object-object) Reference assignment is guaranteed to be atomic on all .NET platforms. Will this code is atomic,

```
public static List<MyType> _items;

public static List<MyType> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (_items== null)
        {
            _items= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyType>>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Items"]);
        }
        return _items;
    }
}
```

I know there might be multiple object as given [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). But will it Items will be atomic(I mean it will be either null or List and not in middle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this code is not atomic - if `Items` is accessed from multiple threads in parallel, `_items` may actually get created more than once and different callers may receive a different value.

This code needs locking because it first performs a read, a branch and a write (after an expensive deserialization call). The read and the write *by themselves* are atomic but - without a lock - there's nothing to prevent the system to switch to another thread between the read and the write.

In pseudo(ish) code, this is what may happen:

```
if (_items==null)
    // Thread may be interrupted here.
{
    // Thread may be interrupted inside this call in many places,
    // so another thread may enter the body of the if() and
    // call this same function again.
    var s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.get_Item("Items");

    // Thread may be interrupted inside this call in many places,
    // so another thread may enter the body of the if() and
    // call this same function again.
    var i = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);

    // Thread may be interrupted here.
    _items = i;
}

// Thread may be interrupted here.
return (_items);
```

This shows you that without locking it's possible for multiple callers to get a different instance of the `Items` list.

You should look into using [`Lazy<T>`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1rarpqvbTAhWBxYMKHcebDiIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdd642331(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHjaIiy6pp3-YbGUyg4L5O3ltG8WQ&sig2=bgEK876lZVdmzSc8drplTw) which will make this sort of initialization a lot simpler and safe.

[When should I use Lazy<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847721/when-should-i-use-lazyt)

Also, keep in mind that `List<T>` itself is *not* thread-safe - you may want to use a different type (like `ConcurrentDictionary<T1, T2>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) or you may need to use locking around *all* operations against this list.

Rob, in the comments, pointed out that the question may be about whether a given assignment is atomic - a single assignment (that is a single write) of a reference is guaranteed to be atomic but that doesn't make this code safe because there's more than a single assignment here.

Comment: This is correct, but I *believe* OP is asking whether or not the *assignment* is atomic. That is, there will never be a 'half constructed' object assigned to `_items`.

Comment: @Rob You could be right - let me update the answer to account for that. Thank you.